# Reading binary from MySql-Database form C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am reading a value from a MySql-Database:

```
Select SomeColumn from SomeTable
```

The datatype of `SomeColumn` is set to `BINARY`.
In C# I receive a string that contains the following:

[image: value format]

What exactly do I receive? The database itself shows the value as a hex value: `0x01080001`

Comment: Could you post your code? Otherwise it's very difficult to help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sur that your data is stored as hex ,  you can convert the hex to byte[] using the function bellow :

```
public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex) {
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

if you are using sql server there is 'FILESTREAM' store  allows  you to access to your binary (blob) using sql or ntfs system .

however , i still don't think storing the binary data to database is a good idea .
if your data smaller then 256K you can store it as blob , however if is bigger then 256k please consider the store it as a file .

**UPDATE** :

> Application designers often face the question of whether to store
>   large objects in a filesystem or in a database. Often this decision is
>   made for application design simplicity. Sometimes, performance
>   measurements are also used. This paper looks at the question of
>   fragmentation – one of the operational issues that can affect the
>   performance and/or manageability of the system as deployed long term.
>   As expected from the common wisdom, objects smaller than 256K are best
>   stored in a database while objects larger than 1M are best stored in
>   the filesystem. Between 256K and 1M, the read:write ratio and rate of
>   object overwrite or replacement are important factors. We used the
>   notion of “storage age” or number of object overwrites as way of
>   normalizing wall clock time. Storage age allows our results or similar
>   such results to be applied across a number of read:write ratios and
>   object replacement rates.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-large-object-storage-in-a-database-or-a-filesystem/

Answer (score 0):

You can parsed to a string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach(byte b in fileBytes)
{
    sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));  
}

var myValue = sb.ToString();
```